# chrome.tabs.create is giving an error - "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined"

Tags: tabs, google-chrome-extension, livequery

My manifest.json contains

```
"content_scripts": [
  {
  "matches": ["http://www.facebook.com/*","https://www.facebook.com/*"],
   "js": ["js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js", "js/jquery.livequery.min.js", "js/script.js"]
  }
]
```

and the contents of script.js are

```
$("#FB_HiddenContainer").livequery(function(){
   chrome.tabs.create({"url":"http://www.google.com"});
});
```

When i open facebook, console reports an error

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'create' of undefined

at

*chrome-extension://whateveristhisweirdcode/js/script.js:2*

**How can i make it  open a new tab??**

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Content scripts can't access most extension APIs; only those listed in [the content scripts doc](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) will work. Instead, use [window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.open)("http://www.google.com") (yes, this *does* create a new tab in Chrome; no, there *aren't* any user settings in Chrome that would change that). If you need more access to the extension APIs, you can use [message passing](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to make your [service worker](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/service_workers/) (manifest version 3) or [event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) (manifest version 2) do things on behalf of the content script.