# Linking to chrome://history through extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, url-scheme

I'm working on a chrome extension that injects a few buttons onto a page **via content script**, and I would like to have a button that links to the history page (chrome://history).

This just opens a blank tab with no URL:

```
window.open("chrome://history", "_blank");
```

And having a hyperlink to the history page directly give me an error:

```
<a href="chrome://history" target="_blank">...</a>

Not allowed to load local resource: chrome://history/
```

[Chrome's Extension API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/match_patterns) doesn't have `chrome://*` listed as a supported scheme for extension pages, which explains the error, but all I want to do is provide a link to the history page.  Is there any way to do this, even if it's a little (or a lot) convoluted?

Thanks!

EDIT: Added that this is done through a content script, I didn't clarify that in the initial post.

Comment: For clarification: this is injection is done in a **content script**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wolf War's answer is correct, however, for a content script an additional step is needed.

You **need** a [background](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) (or better, [event](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages)) page to process the request, since content scripts can't call that API. You need to use [Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging#simple):

```
// Content script
// element is your DOM element
element.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({command: "openHistory"});
});

// Event script
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
  if(command == "openHistory") {
    chrome.tabs.create({'url': 'chrome://history'});
  }
});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I did to get it to work!

You answered this just as I was posting mine, thanks! :D

Answer (score 2):

code in Chrome for opening new active tab with history internal page

```
chrome.tabs.create({'url': 'chrome://history', 'active': true});
```

Comment: I didn't clarify that this is a content script.  [This thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10667178/chrome-tabs-create-is-giving-an-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-call-method) says that content scripts can't access any extension APIs except for parts of [chrome.extension](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/extension).

When I run this, it gives me this error:
`Cannot read property 'create' of undefined`

Comment: @JosephNewman You'll have to message the background/event page to do it.

Answer (score 2):

[Wolf War's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29636347/linking-to-chrome-history-through-extension/29636671#29636671) gave me the idea to send a message to my extension itself and have it launch the tab from there, which worked.

I added this to my content script that injects the button on the page:

```
$("#history_button").click( function() {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
        type: "OPEN_HISTORY"
    });
});
```

And added a corresponding listener in my extension's [background script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) that creates the tab:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener( function(request) {
    if (request.type == "OPEN_HISTORY") {
        chrome.tabs.create({ "url": "chrome://history", "active": true });
    }
});
```